# filesystemwatcher working on one network drive but not on another

Tags: vb.net, csv, filesystemwatcher

For every new entry in csv file, code need to read it & after validating add in another Excel file.
So I have 'filesystemwatcher'  which triggers once 'attridutes' of file/folder is 'changed'. I have compiled exe of my code & created folder structure.

Case 1. Folder structure on local drive
upon new entry in csv, change event occurs & code add entry in Excel

Case 2. Folder structure on network drive 1
upon new entry in csv, change event occurs & code add entry in Excel

Case 3. Folder structure on network drive 2 or local drive of another user
upon new entry in csv, change event does not trigger

please refer to below code on form load

```
    watchfolder = New FileSystemWatcher()

    watchfolder.Path = GunResPath

    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes

    watchfolder.IncludeSubdirectories = False

    ' Only watch csv files.
    watchfolder.Filter = IO.Path.GetFileName(myFile)

    AddHandler watchfolder.Changed, AddressOf logchange

    watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

on button click on form enable raising event is set true
Please help to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystemwatcher has problems that are triggered by long file names, multiple file changes and a bunch of other stuff.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

You can tweak the buffer size, but essentially, it's nothing I'd rely on for anything critical. If you really need to know if a files or a directory has changed, you're probably going to need to scan it periodically.